# Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 / PHP7.4 has broken composer & curl

Tags: apt, upgrade, php

I've recently upgraded from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS & have come across the following issue with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Running `composer install` produces the following error messages:

> `Problem 1 - embed/embed v3.4.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.`

My php version is `PHP 7.4.5 (cli)` which is (checks) the latest stable version.

Running `php -m` shows no sign of the **curl** extension

So I try to install php7.4-curl: `sudo apt install php7.4-curl` - which gives me the following message:

> `The following packages have unmet dependencies.  php7.4-curl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu1) but 7.4.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed`

So from the looks of things the `php7.4-curl` package is requiring an older version of PHP than I currently have installed.

How do I fix this?

I did find [this thread of Stack Overflow about CURL libraries clashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993170/php-7-4-and-ubuntu-18-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-curl-so) - but I seem to be having a different problem & the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 comes with php 7.4 (7.4.3) out of the box but it seems that you're also using a PPA repository by Ondrej Sury which has a different PHP version (7.4.5). Therefore you could either remove the PPA or install everything from that PPA.

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't spotted that, it was a left over from my 18.04 install. `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php` & removing/ reinstalling php7.4 worked.